# CAT(0) references request

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, curvature

I'm working on the half-plane model of hyperbolic geometry and my advisor teacher gave me a metric different from the "classical" one and told me to check if my new space is CAT(0), however, he only briefly explained what this means with a triangle drawing.

Can anybody point me to some basic reference to have a good definition and be able to work this out ?

Thank you.

Comment: Bridson-Haefliger, "Metric spaces of non-positive curvature"

Comment: http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/akp-papers/ballmann-nonpo.pdf

Comment: W.Ballmann, "Lectures on Spaces of Nonpositive Curvature", http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783764352424